# Bind sql stored procedure value with android text view

Tags: java, android, sql

Working with an android app project,database is sql server 2008,I write a sql procedure which is

```
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[getSalesIdtest]    Script Date: 11/08/2016 12:46:00 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[getSalesIdtest]
as
(
select LIDTagp,LIDLen,CurrentNO,LIDTagS,LCompanyID from dbo.SetupListIDC WHERE LIDType = 'slsSalesOrder' AND LCompanyID = '01'
)
UPDATE SetupListIDC SET CurrentNo = CurrentNo + 1 WHERE LIDType = 'slsSalesOrder' AND LCompanyID = '01'
```

sql procedure name is getSalesidtest, bind return value with android textview, for that here I am trying

```
 public void gendata(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.gen) {

                connect = connectionclass(un, pass, db, ip);

                PreparedStatement statement = null;
                try {
                    statement = connect.prepareStatement("EXEC dbo.getSalesIdtest");
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    Log.e("Error 1 here: ", e.getMessage());
                }

                try {
                    rs = statement.executeQuery();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Log.e("error 2 here: ", ex.getMessage());
                }
                try {
                    while (rs.next()) {

                        TextView generateData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.genData);
                        generateData.setText(rs.getString(1));
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    Log.e("Error 3 here: ", e.getMessage());
                }
    }
}
```

I want to bind values(return from sql procedure ) with a text value with button click,button name is gen and add an onclick method which is gendata. There are no error on log.